# Install the database server with a database using the installer

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-2010, deployment, installshield

I am working on a windows form-based project on **VS2010 Professional** using **C#** that involves a (local) database. Right now I'm working with **MySQL connector** (that integrates VS with mySQL database) and using **Wamp Server** as SQL server. After the application deployment I'll provide the user only the installer. So is it possible that **Install Shield** will be able to install the server & the database using its setup wizard? And if possible, then how can I do this? Any pointer?

Please ask if my problem statement is unclear.

Comment: The answer is yes. But please specify your features (components) you want to install. App, MySQL Connector, MySQL Server? Is WAMP necessary or do you only need the MySQL Server? Do you want to support existing MySQL Servers?

Comment: I would like to install wampServer (just because of its small size). I also want to create a database having required tables. And I also want to add dlls of MySQL connector(mysql.data) and some images(.png).

Comment: still waiting for some response!

Comment: Because you asked no specific question. Your question is like: "How can I create an application with Visual Studio?" IS is an IDE for creating complex setup applications. Of course it is capable to do the things you asked for. I suggest you start with an InstallSCript project. You will need at least one Feature and add your files to some components. You should create the DB with an SQL script you can install as Support File and run it from a custom action (OnInstalled-Event) as command-line.

Comment: I'll look for InstallScript if it helps. Thanks